# Evaluate the surface integral?

Tags: integration, vector-spaces

Let $a>0$ and $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2\}$

Evalute:
$$I=\int \int_S(x^4+y^4+z^4) \, \mathrm{d}S$$

may i can use Gauss divergence theorem,here $\hat{n} = \frac{x}{a}\hat{\imath}+\frac{y}{a}\hat{\jmath}+ \frac{z}{a}\hat{k}$

\begin{eqnarray*}
I&=&a\iint_S(x^3\hat{\imath}+y^3\hat{\jmath}+z^3\hat{k})\cdot\hat{n} \, \mathrm{d}S \\ \\
&=&a\iiint_V \nabla.(x^3\hat{\imath}+y^3\hat{\jmath}+z^3\hat{k})\, \mathrm{d}V \\ \\
&=&3a\iint_V (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,\mathrm{d}V \\ \\
&=&3a^3\iiint_V \,\mathrm{d}V \\ \\
&=& 4\pi a^6
\end{eqnarray*}

So, please tell me: am I right or not?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: For future reference, you do not want to use the symbol $\Delta$ in this case. You want to use nabla (the LaTeX code for $\nabla$ is \nabla). $\Delta$ can (and does) mean the Laplacian and can cause confusion.

Comment: Please consider using ``\imath`` and ``\jmath`` to get $\imath$ and $\jmath$ so that the ``\hat`` command gives $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$ instead of $\hat i$ and $\hat j$. Also, consider using ``\iint`` and ``\iiint`` to get $\iint$ and $\iiint$ instead of using ``\int\int`` and ``\int\int\int`` to get $\int\int$ and $\int\int\int$.

Comment: Your answer is almost there, but not quite.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something at the end isn't quite right, but it's mostly there.  The issue is that:

$$dV = r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi.$$

So the $a^6$ part is correct, but the coefficient is a little off:

$$3a\iiint (x^2+y^2+z^2)dV = 3a\iint d\Omega \int (r^4) dr = \frac{12 \pi a^6}{5}.$$

The double integral is over the "solid angle:"

$$\iint d\Omega = \int \sin(\theta)d\theta \int d\phi = 4\pi.$$

Comment: @ John : In your 2nd step,  why can i directly put the values of $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 $ is  $a^2$ in triple integeral .

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\color{#00f}{\LARGE I} \equiv 3\int_{S}z^{4}\,\dd S=3a^{6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\phi
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{4}\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
=-6\pi a^{6}\int_{1}^{-1}t^{4}\,\dd t
=\color{#00f}{\large{12\pi \over 5}\,a^{6}}
$$